# automatically copy cell formatting from one cell to another if a third cell is blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If somebody could please help me.

I have a spreadsheet with column D containing a multitude of plan numbers, In column y there are only a few plan numbers which have different colored backgrounds.

I am trying to automatically copy the background color from column Y's number to column D(because they match/are equal) ONLY IF Column A is blank.

I have tried conditional formatting where column D = column y, but the all the numbers change color even if column A has a value and that is where I am stuck to only have the cell change number if column A is empty.

I hope somebody can help me please.

Comment: sounds like you need to use 'AND()` [to test both conditions] and `ISBLANK`()` [for the column A part]

Comment: You need to post some made up data so we can understand what you are trying to do.  It is also good if you post the conditional posting you tried.

Comment: Could you please share what formula you have used?

Comment: Is column Y coloured by using conditional formatting based on the plan number, or have background colours been applied manually?